# Android Layout Resizing

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout

Using a relative layout for a menu on a game for android, however, launching different size emulators and the layout doesn't scale at all well even though i'm using dip. On a medium screen it works fine, however a small screen cuts half the bottom buttons off and the large screen scrunches all the buttons further up the screen, any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/menubackground"
>
<Button
android:text="High Scores" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="200dp" 
android:id="@+id/HighScore" 
android:layout_below="@+id/NewGame" 
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:textStyle="bold"
></Button>
<Button
android:text="Instructions" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="200dp" 
android:id="@+id/Instructions" 
android:layout_below="@+id/HighScore" 
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:textStyle="bold"
></Button>
<Button
android:text="Exit" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="200dp" 
android:id="@+id/Exit" 
android:layout_below="@+id/Instructions" 
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:textStyle="bold"
>

</Button>
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:textStyle="bold" 
android:id="@+id/NewGame" 
android:text="New Game" 
android:layout_width="200dp" 
android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/HighScore" 
android:layout_marginTop="191dp"></Button>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can I ask, what is it that's not scaling right? The width or height? Or more specifically, which views are getting "cut off" or not showing correctly?

Comment: the last button (exit) is cut off on smaller screens. The width is fine, the height is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a `RelativeLayout` is not the best choice here. What I would do is use a `LinearLayout` in a vertical direction. Using `weight` you can make it so that allow the elements are evenly spaced out no matter the screen size. Perhaps, try something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<Button android:id="@+id/new_game"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="feasdf"
/>
<Button android:id="@+id/instructions"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="feasdf"
/>
<Button android:id="@+id/exit_game"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="feasdf"
/>
```

Let me know if you've got any other questions!

Comment: No problem, just remember to accept this answer if you found it helpful. Just click on the gray check next to this question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Put the `RelativeLayout` into a `ScrollView` [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html). This will display the part that is being cut off on smaller screen sizes. It won't affect larger screen sizes where all the content can be viewed on the screen.

Comment: is there anyway of doing it that doesn't involve having to scroll?

Comment: you could make the buttons smaller